# Why am I able to break the spacemacs SPC SPC leader by missetting an org-mode variable?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

In my .spacemacs dotfile, I have the following under dotspacemacs/user-config:

`(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("~/docs/everything.org")))`

If I move everything.org out of ~/docs/ and then restart-emacs, I see the message “org-agenda-get-day-entries: No such file ~/docs/everything.org”.

But not only that. When I press SPC SPC, I expect to see a helm prompt beginning with “M-x”. Instead, I now get the message “SPC SPC is undefined”.

Either removing the setq line above or revising it (so that the location of everything.org is correct) fixes this problem. But why did it arise in the first place?

Comment: Somewhere in your init file, you are trying to create an agenda: that fails, and probably any settings that are done after that are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs stops evaluation upon error. In this case it tries to get to your everything.org file which isn't there and stops at that very moment. Any settings loaded thus far exist, but any settings loaded after (like the leader key setup) are not loaded.

Long story short: if you reference a file in .el files, make sure that it's there.